# php json_decode a json string sent via cors

Tags: php, json, cors

I was looking around and tried to decode, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
    //Receive the RAW post responseData.
$contentJSON = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));

//Attempt to decode the incoming RAW post responseData from JSON.
$contentDECODED = json_decode($contentJSON , true);
$action = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $contentDECODED["action"]);
$customerID = intval(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $contentDECODED["customerId"])); 
$productID_Array = $contentDECODED[gArrayOfProductIds];
```

`var_dump($productID_Array)` will output:

```
array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["productId"]=>
        int(52979957765)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        ["productId"]=>
        int(69956304901)
      }
      [2]=>
      array(1) {
        ["productId"]=>
        int(69888278533)
      }
    }
```

but `var_dump(implode(",",array_map('intval',$productID_Array)));` will output:

```
"1,1,1"
```

and `var_dump(implode(",",$productID_Array));` will output:

```
"Array,Array,Array"
```

could someone shred some light on my problem?
along side that what would be the best way to sanitize the input from the json?

**HUGE thanks for anyone who might help !**

Comment: Thanks. Was wondering how to approve an answer.

Comment: welcome. I rolled the question back to a previous revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's multidimensional array, you need to get values of "product Id" field before join them

```
implode(",",array_map('intval', array_column($productID_Array, "productId")))
```

Comment: HUGE THANKS to you splash58. you saved me !